# Why is it preferred to transport lower current and higher voltages across the PCB?

Tags: voltage, current

In case of modern PC, the CPU requires fairly lot of power. At nowadays the CPU uses +12V rails and converts this +12V to around +1V in voltage regulator module near the CPU itself. Why is it preferred to transport lower current and high voltages instead of lower voltages and higher current across the motherboard? Is it because of crosstalk?

Comment: For a given track resistance R power dissipated in track = I^2 R - so power goes up as square of I. When using an "ideal"  transformer Vin x Iin  Vout x Iout. So eg 12V x 10A transforms to 1V x 120A. As V goes down I rises proportionately. As current is 12x larger at 1V, power loss is 12^2 = 144 times higher on same track!.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a limit to how low a resistance you can get on pcb power traces. This has two effects. If you put the regulator far from the CPU, you'll get voltage losses on the PCB, due to the effect of current times resistance. More important, there's no way to compensate for these losses, so the regulation of the voltage **at the CPU** will suffer.

EDIT For example, let's say that, with the regulator on the other side of the board, the trace resistance is .02 ohms, while with the regulator close to the CPU, the trace resistance is .005 ohms. Furthermore, let's say that the CPU current varies between 5 and 20 amps. Then

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUK4FX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

shows how the CPU voltage will vary for the two cases. These numbers are not outrageously out of range, and while a variation of .1 volts at the CPU is not a problem, a variation of .4 volts (on 1 volt) is.

As an example, a Pentium E6300 uses a .85 to 1.375 main voltage, with a power dissipation as high as 65 watts, so the peak current might be in the range of 50 amps.

Comment: Maybe a tiny drawing could help. Don't want to hijack your upvotes by saying (nearly) the same, but with graphics two hours later.

Comment: _"More important, there's no way to compensate for these losses ..."_ - Sure there is; just have the regulator do remote sensing at the CPU site, and up-regulate its output voltage to compensate losses.

Answer (score 2):

It's because the higher the current is, the more power is wasted on wires because P = I²R.

But even if you don't care about power, electronics "love" clean and stable voltage, so they always use regulators of all kinds on board, while on wires you transfer whatever you can, with all noises induced from outside, with voltage drops of the wires themselves, etc.